Tracking event from a varient of remote config in google analytics
I have a mobile app, I use remote config to create different paywalls and ABtest them to users. But as I see in the AB test feature in Firebase, all I can track is 7 different metrics. I also figure out that GA4 provides a feature called Explore, where I can sort events and metrics in different dimensions. But I can't find out how to create a custom dimension based on parameters in Remote Config. What should I do? Really sorry if this is a dumb question cause this is my first app
I tried to create a custom definition but the parameter in remote config doesn't appear in the drop down of the parameter section in custom definition
